# Opencv No implementation found for native / Native method not found

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

**LogCat / com.example.jni**

```
01-10 01:58:55.102: D/JavaCameraView(22833): Starting processing thread
01-10 01:58:55.112: E/BufferQueue(22833): [unnamed-22833-1] dequeueBuffer: mMinUndequeuedBuffers=2 exceeded (dequeued=6)
01-10 01:58:55.142: D/JavaCameraView(22833): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 373248
01-10 01:58:55.142: E/BufferQueue(22833): [unnamed-22833-1] dequeueBuffer: mMinUndequeuedBuffers=2 exceeded (dequeued=5)
01-10 01:58:55.162: W/dalvikvm(22833): No implementation found for native Lcom/example/jni/TutorialActivity;.MainActivity:(JJI)V
01-10 01:58:55.162: W/dalvikvm(22833): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bd3438)
01-10 01:58:55.172: E/AndroidRuntime(22833): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2008
01-10 01:58:55.172: E/AndroidRuntime(22833): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.jni.TutorialActivity.MainActivity:(JJI)V
01-10 01:58:55.172: E/AndroidRuntime(22833):    at com.example.jni.TutorialActivity.MainActivity(Native Method)
01-10 01:58:55.172: E/AndroidRuntime(22833):    at com.example.jni.TutorialActivity.onCameraFrame(TutorialActivity.java:133)
01-10 01:58:55.172: E/AndroidRuntime(22833):    at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:387)
01-10 01:58:55.172: E/AndroidRuntime(22833):    at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:328)
01-10 01:58:55.172: E/AndroidRuntime(22833):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-10 01:58:55.182: D/JavaCameraView(22833): Preview Frame received. Frame size: 373248
01-10 01:58:55.192: D/JavaCameraView(22833): Disconnecting from camera
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC

include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndklib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TutorialActivity.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := set.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hand_calc.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hand_core.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hand_define.h
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**jni/TutorialActivity.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <hand_define.h>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <hand_calc.cpp>
#include <hand_core.cpp>
#include <set.cpp>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
    extern "c"{

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_TutorialActivity_MainActivity
      (JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong addrRgb, jlong addrsss, jint btnclick);

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_TutorialActivity_MainActivity
      (JNIEnv *, jobject, jlong addrRgb, jlong addrsss, jint btnclick)
    {
    .
    .
    .
    }

    }
```

**TutorialActivity.java**

```
       package com.example.jni;

        import java.io.FileOutputStream;

        public class TutorialActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2  {
        .
        .
        .
        private BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
                @Override
                public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
                    switch (status) {
                        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                        {
                            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                            System.loadLibrary("ndklib");

                            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                        } break;
                        default:
                        {
                            super.onManagerConnected(status);
                        } break;
                    }
                }
            };
        .
        .
        .
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final int viewMode = mViewMode;       

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        MainActivity(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(), sss.getNativeObjAddr(), btnclick);
        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        btnclick = 1;
                        MainActivity(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(), sss.getNativeObjAddr(), btnclick);
                        //Core.normalize(sss, sss, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_8U);
                        Utils.matToBitmap(sss, mbit);
                        mimg.setImageBitmap(mbit);
                        btnclick = 0;
                    }           
                });
            return mRgba;
        }

            public native void MainActivity(long Rgba, long Hand, int Clk);
}
```

First, sorry about my poor coding skill.

I'm trying using c++ code on java with jni. When i copied and edited code-body from Opencv for Android sample Tutorial-2 , my c++ codes worked well. but when i tried from a new Android app Project with the way likes tutorial-2, it doesn't work and shows "Opencv No implementation found for native / Native method not found" even there any errors.

Project's perperties
*c/c++build 
build command : ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd
Behaviour - Auto build : checked

*c/c++ general - paths and symbols - JNUc++
added some directories.